# How to count the adjacent values with values of 1 in a geotiff array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's that we have geotiff of `0` and `1`.

```
import rasterio
src = rasterio.open('myData.tif')
data = src.read(1)
data
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

I would like to have for each pixel `1` the sum of all adjacent pixels forming a cluster of ones and to have something like the following:

```
array([[0, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Can you explain why the values position (1,3) and (3,0) are 1 and 1?

Comment: Because they do not "touch" any other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html):

```
from scipy.ndimage import label

out = np.zeros_like(data)

labels, N = label(data)
for i in range(N):
    mask = labels==i+1
    out[mask] = mask.sum()
```

output:

```
array([[0, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 3]])
```